# CKEditor v4 Remove / Change Button Title Attribute

Tags: ckeditor, accessibility, ckeditor4.x

On CKEditor V4 all the editor buttons include a title attribute which triggers 50 errors on my client accessibility software.

Although we advised that this is not really an issue since the issue is caused because the title attribute exists with a different text that is on the button, the client insists this issue needs to be fixed.

Upgrading to V5 is not a possibility.

Is it possible to remove the title attribute from CKEditor buttons (ex: Bold, Italic, Font...)?

Is there another way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the accessibility software flagging it? There is nothing in WCAG that says the tooltip should be the same text as the button. This is not an error and sounds like a bug in the accessibility software.

Comment: @slugolicious they have their own software, based on axe-core, that does validations for all websites under the parent company and it's their base of truth. I believe they added some of their own "business rules" to complement correct copyright when applying accessibility. Therefore in an item has text, either there is no title or the title attribute must match the text.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **You should not remove the `title` attribute, it is deteriorating usability and therefore accessibility**.

> A user’s understanding of an icon is based on previous experience. Due to the absence of a standard usage for most icons, text labels are necessary to communicate the meaning and reduce ambiguity.

– [Icon Usability by NN/g](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/)

---

It might still be interesting how one would go about reliably changing toolbar buttons’ properties.

A lot of articles work directly on the DOM, which is a hack and sensitive to side-effects. You never know when a component is re-rendering its DOM.

The editor titles come from the [toolbar configuration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/toolbar.html#advanced-toolbar-configurator), specifically from `config.toolbar[*].items[*].title`.

You will need to apply an [“Item by Item” Configuration](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/toolbarconcepts.html#item-by-item-configuration) by creating a function to remove titles from the configuration.

I couldn’t figure out how to intervene each time when a new config part is loaded, for example by plug-ins, so in the example `editorConfig` is only called once with an object that does not define `toolbar`.

```js
   // This should go in the config.js file

const removeToolbarTitles = c => ({
   ...c,
   toolbar: [
      c.toolbar?.map(t => ({
        ...t,
        items: Array.isArray(t.items) ? t.items.map(i => removeItemTitle(i)) : t.items
      }))
   ]
});

const removeItemTitle = i => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(i).filter(e => e[0] !== 'title'));

/* Change any loaded config file to remove titles */
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = removeToolbarTitles;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.22.1/standard/ckeditor.js" integrity="sha384-IBDNY5TVKWr+u1841ldzW99oyOoUBpoGeouNuoXVwF0PBFR3v10dzwm09xNIEeiG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```